# Angular Material tabs are not rendered at all

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use the Angular Material Tabs Module but it's not rendered properly. Instead of the tabs, just the text is being displayed.

I'm using Angular 6, with Angular Material version 6.4.7

I followed the setup procedure described on https://v6.material.angular.io/guide/getting-started (npm installation, no snapshots)

Then I did some research on common pitfalls. I checked the proper imports, made sure the stylesheet is imported and that I use the BrowserAnimationsModule as well as the base module MatInputModule. In fact, none the of the answers on Stackoverflow helped me solve the issue.

This is what the respective section in my template looks like:

```
        <mat-tab-group>
            <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
```

As some other responses point out missing import, I double checked. Here are my imports in the app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
```

They are also define in the @NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatTabsModule,
```

I also checked for the imported theme: here are the respective lines in my index.html file:

```
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I would expect the tabs to be displayed, but instead only the Text is displayed: [image]

So obviously I'm forgetting something. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Your web server can' serve anything from node_modules. Do as the getting started guide says: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme.

Comment: I did in fact try that as well. However, I'm not sure to which file I need to add it. I don't have a styles.css file, but a global.scss file, so I added it there -> no success.

Comment: You're not using the standard CLI project structure, so we can't know how you configured your project. If you want to use a link to a css file in your index.html, then copy it to the assets directory (assuming your project does have an assets directory, since it doesn't seem to use the standard CLI layout), and use the path to that file instead of a path to node_modules.

Comment: It's a generated project using jHipster, so I assumed the setup should follow some standard layouting.

Anyway, is it safe to say that it's most likely related to shylesheet linking?

Answer (score 0):

I faced **exact** same issue when one component is displaying correctly but not the other one in same module.

Check if you miss out adding your component (example: **MyTestComponent**) under declarations section in your module, example:

```
declarations: [
   ...,
   MyTestComponent
]
```